# What is PHP-FPM doing actually?

Tags: php-fpm

I followed [the steps to install](https://tecadmin.net/install-multiple-php-version-apache-ubuntu/) PHP5.6 and PHP7.1 side by side on an Apache server, using FastCGI. One of the steps is to install and start `php-fpm`. However, when I stop this service, the PHP systems still work.

So, what is `php-fpm` actually doing if disabling it doesn't affect the server?

Comment: you're probably still using old `mod_php` instead of new `php-fpm`..

Comment: @alexus but the two different versions work, so I'd say FastCGI is 'active' somehow

Comment: if after stopping php-fpm, you're still getting php code rendered, that means you're still using old mod_php as otherwise you'd get blank page

Comment: Are you sure you followed the steps exactly like in the tutorial with the test sites which shows which api is activated? Did you actually see fpm in the API field?

Comment: @Broco I use `phpinfo()` to see which version is being used. And the two configs show different PHP versions. The Apache config of these sites use `Action php-fastcgi /cgi-bin/phpXX.fastcgi` as their config. `phpinfo()` says `Server API CGI/FastCGI`.